# My stock broker gave me two 1099-Bs. Should I file two Schedule-Ds?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 1099-b, schedule-d

Robinhood is my broker and this year I decided to file my Federal and state taxes by myself.

Robinhood gave me two 1099-Bs for last year. Half of my transactions are on one 1099-B and the other half on the other.

I don't need to fill out 8949 as all the basis has been reported to IRS and I have not adjustments on any of my transactions.

Now, do I need to fill in two Schedule-D forms for each of the 1099-Bs or can I add up my totals from the 1099-Bs and put them on the Schedule-D?

note: Robinhood changed it's clearinghouse last year. 
https://blog.robinhood.com/news/2018/10/9/introducing-clearing-by-robinhood So they gave me two 1099-Bs one for the old clearinghouse and one for the new clearinghouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as you would combine 1099-Bs from different brokers onto one Schedule D, you should combine the two 1099-Bs from the same broker. This assumes that each transaction is listed on exactly one of the 1099-Bs and there are no discrepancies. Your situation sounds unusual (assuming you don't in fact have two different *accounts* with the broker) -- typically a second 1099-B would be labeled as a corrected replacement (rather than a supplement) to the first, but you say you have verified that this is not the case.

Comment: Robinhood changed it's clearinghouse last year. https://blog.robinhood.com/news/2018/10/9/introducing-clearing-by-robinhood

So they gave me two 1099-Bs one for the old clearinghouse and one for the new clearinghouse :-) 

Thank you.